# Navigating to create record page Salesforce1 sforce.one.nativgateToURL

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

So I am trying to redirect to the edit page of a record to pass parameters.  For the desktop browser everything works fine.  However, for SF1 I get a "Looks like there's a problem error"

Is the relative URL I'm passing incorrect?  How can I navigate to the Record Create page in SF1?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {

    if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce != null) {
        sforce.one.navigateToURL('/a05/e');
    } else {
        window.open('/a05/e', '_self');
    }
}, 1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `createRecord(​entityName​[, recordTypeId])` (pulled from [Navigation with the sforce.one Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)).

> **createRecord(​entityName​[, recordTypeId])**
>
> Opens the page to create a new record for the specified `entityName`, for example, `“Account”` or `“MyObject__c”`.
> `recordTypeId` is optional and, if provided, specifies the record type for the created object.

Example:

```
if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce != null) {
    sforce.one.createRecord('MyObject__c');
}
```

Comment: I get a "You don't have access to this record.  Ask your administrator.  However, I'm system admin.  Is there an other permission I need?

Comment: Also, it works in the browser which leads me to believe I have access to the record create/edit from that vForce page

Comment: Maybe you need to specify a `recordTypeId`?

Comment: nevermind.  Looks like the API Name is case sensitive.  I had WorkDay__c and it needed to be Workday__c

Comment: Makes sense. It is `Javascript`.